# Unobtrusive Client Validation without accepting model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have simple form like this which accepts only two values string action and editText.Is there a way to enable Unobtrusive Client Validation on this without Data Annotations? Or do I have to accept model and use Data Annotations? I just need it to make sure editText is atleast 5 chars long.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "error", UpdateTargetId = "Pcedit" + @Model.ID}))
    {                                  
    <textarea rows="3" cols="2" name="editText" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Save"/>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel"/>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unobtrusive client validation uses jquery.validate I believe?  So just invoke it directly on the client, using javascript.  Something like:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    editText: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    }
  }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength

Comment: It won't use unobtrusive validation though, and separates the view from the backing model. This way, you are implementing pure javascript validation. With unobtrusive validation with mvc, you only need to define the validation properties once, and they are used with both client side and server side validation. Now you only have client side, so you need to do the server validation separately.

Comment: I would love to know how you got this to work. Adding $("form").validate() with some rules is totally ignored for me. It seems like unobtrusive is taking control of things and it doesn't look like you can mix pure jQuery client validation rules in there.